# Creating a complex number so that its norm equals to 1

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like to create a complex number `c` so that its norm is equal to some number `a` (for the purpose of this question let's assume `a = 1`) if I already have either its real or imaginary part. I know that:
$$\lVert \mathbf{c} \rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1} ^{n} c_i \overline{c_i}}.$$
In this case:
$$\lVert \mathbf{c} \rVert = \sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)} = \sqrt{a^2+abi-abi-b^2i^2} = \sqrt{a^2-b^2\cdot{-1}} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$
As I said, we already know either `a` or `b`, let's say we know that `a = 2`. How can I find what must `b` be equal to if the norm must be `1`? Some simple equations:
$$ \sqrt{2^2+b^2} = 1 \iff 2^2+b^2 = 1 \iff 4+b^2 = 1 \iff b^2 = 1 - 4 \iff b^2 = -3 \iff b =  \pm\sqrt{-3} \iff $$

$$ \iff b = \pm\sqrt{3} * \sqrt{-1} \iff b = \pm\sqrt{3}i $$
Okay, so based on the above eqations, the imaginary part can be $\pm\sqrt{3}i$. So let's say $c=2+\sqrt{3}i$. But clearly my equations are wrong, because:
$$\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{3}i)(2-\sqrt{3}i)} = \sqrt{7},$$ which does not equal to `1`. Please, help me with my confusion and lack of knowledge.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. First you mention that $c$ is a complex number. But then $c$ suddenly has $n$ components? Besides, you cannot have $\|c\| = 1$ if one of the components is already larger than $1$...

Comment: Note that $b$ in your case is real number it is cannot be complex $|a+ib| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ if $a=2$ for sure $|a+ib|\geq 2$

Comment: There is no complex number with norm 1 and real part equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

You can't just use any number for $a$ and $b$! If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, which they are, their square is always positive or zero, which can only be the case if $|a| \leq 1$ and/or $|b| \leq 1$ are less than or equal to 1!

$$
\begin{align*}
a^{2} + b^{2} &= 1 \quad\mid\quad -\left(b^{2}\right)\\
a^{2} &= 1 - b^{2} \quad\mid\quad \sqrt{~~}\\
a &= \sqrt{1 - b^{2}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

If you got an $b > 1$ then will $1 - b^{2}$ get negative and the squareroot of something negativ is not real aka $b$ can't be greater then $1$ but you chose one $b$ or $a$ greater than $1$.

You can also explain it to yourself graphic by imagining the complex number as versor. Of course, the versor is longer (total length) than one [unit] if it is greater than one [unit] in either direction (real part or imaginary part).

**Creating complex numbers with the norm $1$**

According to the trigonometric Pythagoras there is $\cos(x)^{2} + \sin(x)^2 = 1$ and according to the euler's formula there is $z = e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} = \cos(x) + \sin(x) \cdot \mathrm{i}$.

When you combine these you will get $|z| = |e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}}| = 1$ because $|z| = |e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}}| =  |\cos(x) + \sin(x) \cdot \mathrm{i}| = \cos(x)^{2} + \sin(x)^2 = 1$.

Aka can chose any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to get a complex number wich has the norm $1$!

E.G.
$$x = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$z = \cos(x) + \sin(x) \cdot \mathrm{i} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot \mathrm{i}$$
$$z = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot \mathrm{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$|z| = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}}| = 1$$

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation of why my approach was wrong. Using the euler's formula to create a number is a great idea. I didn't know the norm can be computed using $cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2$. As you said, the `x` can be any real number because the euler's formula for each real `x` "produces a circle of size 1" if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @Slan Yes indeed. That is correct. Please.^^

Answer (score 3):

Take any nonzero complex number $c=a+bi$.  Divide by it's length, which is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to get a complex number of length $1$.

$$z = \frac{c}{||c||}= \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}i.$$

Compute the length of $z$ to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you for a simple and straight answer. It indeed does work. I accepted the answer from @KevinDietrich, because his answer is more explanatory and as clearly seen from my "dumb" question I need some explanations because otherwise, I won't learn a lot. I can't upvote your answer yet, will do so in the future (if I gain enough reputation).